# Combinations with Piano Keys

Tags: probability, combinations, problem-solving

How many sound combinations can be created by the $10$ selected piano keys if each sound combination contains from $3$ to $10$ keys?

Can anyone throw at least a hint? I am having difficulties with this question.

Comment: You may not know how to solve this exact problem, but you aren't solving this problem in a complete vacuum. You probably know how to handle some similar problems (like, what if you had to have _exactly_ $3$ keys, or what if there was _no_ restriction on the number of keys in a combination?) What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck, and why? If you tell us these things, it's much easier for us to make a solution that will actually be helpful.

Comment: Also remember that nobody here was sitting next to you when you encountered this problem, so you have seen information we have not. For example, what is a "sound combination"? Is it produced by striking all three (or more) keys simultaneously, or do you strike them one at a time and consider the same keys in a different sequence to be a different "sound combination"? (The musical terms for these two possibilities are "chord" and "melody".)

Comment: It may be easier to first find the number of sound combinations that can be created with 1 to 10 keys, then subtract the number that only use 1 or 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Each combination can have $3$ to $10$ keys which means for a certain group of selected piano keys to be called a combination, at least $3$ keys *must* be played. For keys other than these $3$, there are two possibilities, either being played or not. What follows is simply the principle of counting.

Comment: So 3 keys must be played at once to be called a combination ? Can it be 4 or 5 keys too ?

Comment: Yes as your question states each sound combination contains $3$ to $10$ keys. Yes it can be, however, it may or may not be, that is it has $2$ possibilities either of being played or not.